# Liability as a project manager

Tags: liability, property, advice

I am offering project management services to a group of people wanting to buy some property.I would like to say something like this:
"Any advice I will give to the client will either be based on the best of my knowledge or based on information from a professional advisors chosen by the client, for which I personally will not take liability."
Is this acceptable to avoid liability or is there better wording?

Comment: You may look into professional liability insurance.  Such is very cheap, I think I was paying about $100/yr for 1 million in coverage.  Even perfect wording will not prevent you from being sued, but liability will normally insulate you from many of the negatives of just someone bringing a law suit.

Comment: You may be surprised to learn that the law is generally not written with an eye toward allowing people to exempt themselves from its requirements.

Comment: Where? Laws are not the same everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this acceptable to avoid liability or is there better wording?

There is not nearly enough information for assessing whether the statement precludes a finding of liability.

Consider the following issues:

- The nature and scope of your contract are unclear. For instance, your
  client's intent to buy real estate might have no relevance to your
  role of project manager, or the latter might inevitably trigger
  duties no realtor can lawfully elude. It is impossible to tell which scenario applies in your matter.
- The legislation in the applicable --and unspecified-- jurisdiction(s)
  might void or supersede your no-liability clause.
- It is doubtful that advice "*based on the best on your knowledge*"
  and "*based on information [from a third party]*" will always be
  mutually exclusive.
- The clause seems limited to liability for detrimental advice, thereby leaving all other sorts of liability unaddressed even if they also pertain to project management.

There is no magic, *one-size-fits-all* wording for addressing issues of liability.

Comment: Also, waivers of liability that extent to intentional acts, willful and wanton conduct, bad faith, or gross negligence are generally not enforceable.